# CakePHP: How to update the Models PHPDocs?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpdoc

I have a huge project with 100+ tables in my database. Over the years, we add some new columns in some tables, but we forgot to reflect this on Models [phpDocs](https://www.phpdoc.org/). Those phpdocs were initially generate by [cake bake model](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/tags-and-users.html#cms-tutorial-tags-and-users) in the beginning of our project.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * Pessoa Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $numero_documento_principal
 * @property string $nome
 * @property string $tipo_pessoa
 * @property string $cidade_natural
 * @property string $nacionalidade
 * @property string $estado_natural
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $data_obito
 * @property string $sexo
 * @property string $nome_genitor
 * @property string $nome_genitora
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $data_nascimento
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\EnderecoPessoa[] $endereco_pessoa
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Parte[] $parte
 */
class Pessoa extends Entity {}
```

Those docs are very important nowadays thanks auto-complete features used in VSCode and similars IDEs.

The problem is: **if we try to generate by bake again, all custom code will be replaced by the original bake generated one**.
Is there a away to avoid this and update only the phpDocs part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a version control system and revert the changes that you do not need after baking, or use **[`dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper`](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper)**, which can [**update annotations**](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper/blob/1.18.3/docs/Annotations.md).

Alternatively check if the upcoming [**(partially) non-destructive baking**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/releases/tag/2.8.0-RC1) functionality works for your needs.